# Why two similar PCs have different internet speed

Tags: wired-networking, internet-speed

I have two servers on my home network lab and both have wired connection. Here is the network spec:

- DC1: Windows Server 2019/Primary DC/Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
- DC2: Windows Server 2022/Secondary DC/Intel 82574L Gigabit Network Connection

When I test my internet speed on the same site, I get below result:

- DC1: 300 Mbps
- DC2: 90 Mbps

Both have static IP/DNS

What could be the reason they have different speed? How can I diagnose the issue?

What is the best tool that can help me figure it out?
Is there any other component that might affect the performance?

**Edit**: All my cables are high quality. I have a workstation PC which it also cannot exceed 90 Mbps. I used [TCPOptimizer](https://www.speedguide.net/downloads.php) tool on it but nothing changed. IPv6 is disabled on all my machines.

Comment: Are they both configured to use Gigabit speeds? Have you checked the wires? Can you reach speeds higher than 90 within your local network?

Comment: Please see my edit. I don't know about configuring the adapter, I'll research about it.

Comment: Are you testing them at the same time? Make sure other hosts are not using any of the Internet-to-router bandwidth when testing one host.

Comment: No, I test only one of them each time. I tested many times and I always got the same results.

Comment: Always try swapping the cables over. I would check the router to see if all ports are set to auto, since a mismatch may result in ports being half-duplex. I would also try booting a Linux disk and test with that, and look at the output of `ethtool`.